# Descriptor on method provides metadata but can't get the class the method is located in

Tags: python, decorator, descriptor

Please forgive my interchanging uses of descriptor and decorator.  I may have some of them wrong here.

I want to write (lots) of classes that declaratively specify something about their methods as such:

```
class Foo:

    @method_metadata(0,1,2)
    def some_method(self,input):
        print("I received some input: "+input)
```

The intent is not to alter the behavior of the method, just to register that (0,1,2) are associated with this method.

I've written the following descriptor to pull this off.  It's giving me two out of three things I need:

```
class method_metadata:

    # 1 - I need to gather three things here: the parameters passed into the method descriptor (0,1,2) in my case
    # 2 - A reference to the method so I can call it later
    # 3 - The class that the method lives in - this is the one I can't figure out

    def __init__(self,*collection_args):

        # Achieved #1 here
        self.collection_args = collection_args

    def __call__(self,decorated_function):

        #Achieved #2 here:
        self.decorated_method = decorated_method

        #I'm not sure how to achieve #3 here.

        # inspect.getmembers(decorated_function) showed some promise, not sure if I should pursue that.

        # Alternatively, if I put a descriptor on the class that contains the method, I can iterate through the attributes and get what I need.  That'll be my fall-back solution but in my case it causes a bit of a problem because some attributes aren't happy to be read yet (they throw assertions because they're not initialized, etc).

        return decorated_function
```

Any ideas how to figure out inside method_metadata that the method in question belongs to the Foo class?

PS - I'm on Python 3.2 and have no need for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

At the point a class member (function or class data member) is defined, it is not aware of the enclosing class.  The way the `class` keyword works in Python is that the expressions within the body of the `class` statement are evaluated, packed into a `dict` and then passed to the metaclass (by default, `type`) as `metaclass(classname, bases, members)`.  At the point they're evaluated (which includes applying decorators) there is no way to reference the class that they will eventually be added to.

The way to "do stuff with" metadata that needs to know about the enclosing class is to use a metaclass or class decorator; either:

```
class Foo(metaclass=supporting_metaclass):
```

or

```
@supporting_class_decorator
class Foo:
```

There's not too much difference in effect, and a class decorator has the advantage that you're starting from a fully specified class rather than having to build it yourself so tends to be simpler to write; also, class decorators can be chained.

Either way you're going to need to build in some level of cooperation between the meta/decorating class machinery and the method decorators, and preferably put in a canary so you don't forget one or the other (e.g. make the decorated method non-callable without the meta/class decorator).